# How do you add information into a listbox using a combobox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is what I have now and it adds the selected item from the combobox into the listbox,

```
private void MajorsComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RequirementsListBox.Items.Add(MajorsComboBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

But I want to add other data to the listbox that is not the selected item in  the combobox by clicking an item in the combobox.

The combobox is filled with titles of majors to study in college. I'm trying to fill the list box with the requirements for those majors, like the classes you have to take, by just clicking on the major in the combobox.

Comment: So you want to add all the item in the combobox to the listbox as soon as you click on one? What is the _other data_ you want to add?

Comment: The combobox is filled with titles of majors to study in college. I'm trying to fill the list box with the requirements for those majors, like the classes you have to take, by just clicking on the major in the combobox.

Comment: Okay and where are you keeping those requirements? Are they in a List or something else?

Comment: I was told to create a file that contains the major requirements and populate the listbox with the file. I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Can I just create a word document for each major's requirements and use that as a file or is there some other way?

Comment: By file you mean a text file? If yes then i think it's simpler than a word document. And do you have a text file for each major or only one file with everything in it?

Comment: He means a text file I'm pretty sure. I have all of the information I would just need to make a text file then which I'm not sure how to do. And I think it would be easier to make a text file for each major right? So they could be attributed to the specific items in the combobox. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Ya if you had a text file for each major it would be easier. I added an answer that could probably help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this which would add the content of the file to the listbox :

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.Clear();

    if(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Computer Science")
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(File.ReadAllText(ComputerScienceFile));
    }
    else if(comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Mathematics")
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(File.ReadAllText(MathematicsFile));
    }
}
```

This is the xml of the combobox :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question you can mark it as answered :)

Comment: So I added using system.IO at the top so it could access the file, but when I type the name of the file into the () after ReadAllText it tells me that the name doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @MarkMandela You need to create a variable lets say `string myFile = @"C:\Users\You\Documents\myText.txt"` and then you can use it.

Comment: Thank you, it displays it now. Do you know how to get it to display the data one after another in rows instead of all horizontally though? Is that something I change in the properties of the listbox?

Comment: @MarkMandela If you add the information in your text file as rows they will display as rows.